# Close unused JDBC PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, batch-processing

I have an application in which I am generating a batch of prepared statements. At the moment, if anything is added to the batch whatsoever, then I run executeBatch() and close() the statement.

My question is, if the statement is prepared, but no batch is ever added, and the statement is **never executed**, should I still run close() on the prepared statement in order to prevent a memory leak? Will close() run properly?

Comment: You should always close a Statement, but you should not call `close()` directly.  You should always create your PreparedStatement in a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) clause, so it will be closed automatically.

Comment: @VGR The caveat being that try-with-resources didn't exist prior to Java 7, so in versions before that, you need to use a finally block to close them if they aren't null.

Comment: Thanks @vgr

Down the rabbit hole again I suppose. At least the improvements made thus far have been noticeable!